# Diffeomorphism on $\mathbb C$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $P= a_{0} z^{n}  +a_{1} z^{n-1}+  \cdots +a_{n}$, with $ a_{0} \neq 0,z \in \mathbb C$.

I don't know why $P$ fails to be a local diffeomorphism only at the zeros of the derivative polynomial $P'(z)= \sum  a_{n-j}  j z^{j-1} $

Comment: It's not locally injective at the zeros of $P'$. At the zeros, it has basically the form $w + c\cdot(z-z_0)^k$ with $k > 1$.

Comment: Reading again, if your question is why it is a local diffeomorphism at all points with $P'(z) \neq 0$, the answer using real analysis is that the real Jacobian determinant is $\lvert P'(z)\rvert^2$, so the inverse function theorem settles it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: maybe one of you can post this as an answer?!

Answer (score 3):

If we have a real-differentiable function $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$, where $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, with real part $u$ and imaginary part $v$, then its Jacobian matrix in real form is

$$J_f^{\mathbb{R}} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix},$$

and in complex form, with the Wirtinger derivatives, it is

$$J_f^{\mathbb{C}} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}\\
\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

For a holomorphic $f$, the Cauchy-Riemann equations yield

$$\det J_f^{\mathbb{R}} = \det J_f^{\mathbb{C}} = \lvert f'\rvert^2,$$

so a holomorphic function is a local diffeomorphism at all points where the derivative does not vanish by the (real) inverse function theorem.

---

Computation of the determinants:

- Complex form: The Cauchy-Riemann equations have the form $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}} = 0$. Since we always have $\frac{\partial \overline{g}}{\partial z} = \overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial\overline{z}}}$ and $\frac{\partial \overline{g}}{\partial \overline{z}} = \overline{\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}}$, we have
  $$J_f^{\mathbb{C}} = \begin{pmatrix}f' & 0\\ 0 & \overline{f'}\end{pmatrix}$$
  and $\det J_f^{\mathbb{C}} = \lvert f'\rvert^2$.
- Real form: The Cauchy-Riemann equations are $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$ in real form, and that gives $\det J_f^{\mathbb{R}} = u_xv_y - u_yv_x = u_x^2 + v_x^2$. Now, $$\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} &= \frac12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\\
  &= \frac12\left(u_x+iv_x - i(u_y+iv_y)\right)\\
  &= \frac12\left((u_x+v_y) + i(v_x-u_y)\right)\\
  &= u_x + iv_x,
  \end{align}$$
  so $\lvert f'\rvert^2 = u_x^2 + v_x^2$.